# Running Tensorflow graph multiple times over different input parameters: what kind of loop is efficient?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, while-loop, parallel-processing, control-flow

For my particular problem, I need to re-run the once-constructed Tensorflow graph multiple times, each time re-initializing the variables to new values. Each execution of the graph is independent of the next. Think of it as setting up a model, and then training it 30 independent times with random initialisation per simulation. While I can achieve the above by placing my Session.run() statements inside of a for loop, I do not think that guarantees parallelism.

So the question is: What would be the most appropriate, Tensorflow-compatible way to run multiple independent sims? Should I do session.run() inside a python while loop, or should I perhaps employ the Tensorflow while_loop structure?

Comment: What kind of parallelism do you expect? Do you have multiple GPUs? Multiple machines?

Comment: I have access to a cluster with multiple GPUs. Also, idk, what about the multiple CPU cores? Is there really no benefit in logically decoupling the code?

Comment: I don't think that running multiple sessions on one device works. CPU is one device as far as TF is concerned. So I'm asking whether running a model per device is good enough for you or not

Comment: I guess I was hoping for some black magic in the background :P So what you're saying is that my best bet would be to manually assign separate sessions to individual devices, if multiple devices are available. TensorFlow will not auto-magically "distribute" my ops, even if they're formed correctly and no inter-dependencies exist. Well, there is a shared graph, of course... I imagine separate runs would need their own variables, anyway. Perhaps I should just settle on multiple graphs + multiple sessions.

Comment: I am afraid there is nothing that would help with the problem. Graph itself is a cheap meta-construct and reusing a graph does not make much sense. You, of cause, can create a separate set of variables on each GPU, wire them into your graph using an `if` statement and run everything within a single session. But i hardly see any benefit of that. To solve the problem at hand I would write a bash script, that would start your model multiple times at once (with a for loop) on separate GPUs using distinct ./logdir folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and I'm woking with ensembles of models myself.

First of all, training models in a loop does so in series; neither Python loops or `tf.while_loop` will give you any parallelism across instances.  That being said, (`tf.while_loop` combined with `tf.slice` can be a very efficient way to process minibatches of data, albeit in serial).

One place to start would be looking at the "Distributed TensorFlow" guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).  There's an extensive discussion of how to generate multiple concurrent (asynchronous) sessions.  You can create sessions on the same device or across the network. I think this is capable of the the kind of parallelism you have in mind (what the author calls "Between Graph Replication" with "Asynchronous Training").

A second idea would be to *stack* your instances within a single model by adding and additional "instance" dimension to all your tensors.  You'd also have to similarly stack your training data input (via feed-dict, queue, or dataset). You'd need to take particular care not to cross-link nodes across the individual instances (i.e. the new instance dimensions), but you could train them simultaneously by computing a shared cost function and using a standard optimizer.  When optimized, each component of your weights and values in the instance dimension would represent a single simple model.  You could additionally have an op to compute the vector of individual costs to monitor while training.  This may not speed things up on your cpu (it could take number of instances * single instance time), but if you have a gpu, it might have a great deal of additional parallel capacity for these expanded matrix ops in a similar number of cycles as your single training session.

Looking forward to hearing about what works for you!

UPDATE:

I was apparently incorrect about parallelism, in `tf_while_loop`.  From  (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop:

> while_loop implements non-strict semantics, enabling multiple iterations to run in parallel. The maximum number of parallel iterations can be controlled by parallel_iterations, which gives users some control over memory consumption and execution order. For correct programs, while_loop should return the same result for any parallel_iterations > 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! After coducting more research, I have also realised that distributed TF is the way to go. I have not adjusted my program to incorporate graph replication yet, so I can not tell you just yet what works for me and what doesn't, but I definitely see the light at the end of the tunnel.

Will I be correct in assuming that you use the TF distributed interface for your own ensemble models?

Comment: @anna-earwen, I'm still in the process of evaluating options and benchmarking- and probably serial training will be acceptable for my needs - so not doing distributed yet.  I did discover that I can make single instances of my code faster by 1) storing data in `tf.constant` (and accessing via the `tf.data`/iterator scheme) rather than using a `feed_dict`, or 2) using `while_loop` and `tf.slice` to generate minibatches.  The relative speeds are 6:3:1 for feed_dict:dataset:while_loop.  My dataset is small- so overhead in minibatching (or maybe touching the Python thread) bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is structuring your code like this:

```
def build_graph():
    [stuffs]
    return operations_to_run

operations = []
for graph_no in range(NGRAPHS):
    operations.append(build_graph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(operations)
```

this should grant tensorflow taking care of parallelizing the computations along the graph.

Comment: In this case, will I be creating a list of graphs, or a list of graph operations? But putting all operations into a list seems like a good idea - thanks!

Comment: you are creating a list of operations in the same graph. To create different graphs, you should put a `with tf.Graph.as_sefault()` while calling buld_graph, but it has the problem that different graphs need different sessions, and so you loose parallelism